# Do I need a backend for my reactjs web app.?

Tags: reactjs

Hi I’m building a front end web app using reactjs, my app will map over different array of dogs/cats/animals with multiple props and a couple images each. The ui has a search box which then filters out relevant animals.

My question is if my list were to get quite large, do I need to have it stored in a back end ? Or can it all be stored in front end, there will be no sensitive information or anything. So im not worried about security.  I do not need to receive any information from the users. Basically it’s just a website for people to browse through.

And my second question. Once deploying to a host, Im currently leaning towards AWS. Is updating/adding/subtracting from my arrays simple as deleting the file and adding the new one into the bucket ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds exciting! But let's first back up a bit, and take stock of what we're trying to do. Essentially: we want an app that will show a bunch of images with functionality (e.g. filtering).

All images/photos (e.g. [this cat photo](https://images.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940)) are hosted somewhere. Period. So, you can be the one responsible for hosting the images, or you could just have `<img />` tags in your react app and refer to an existing img src links, where the image sources are being hosted by someone else.

---

So to answer your question: `my question is if my list were to get quite large, do I need to have it stored in a back end ?`

Not necessarily - if you're just referencing a bunch of images from a site that someone else is already hosting, then you're good.

As for this point: `Or can it all be stored in front end, there will be no sensitive information or anything.`

This question is kinda hard to answer, because nothing is really ever 'stored' in the front-end (let's ignore caching). Images live on the server, and the client (e.g. your chrome browser) makes requests to the server to get the images.

---

Now: if you want to upload your own photos or let users upload their photos. That's a very different story.

You would want to use [s3 buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html). They could host your images.

However, based upon your post, I really think you should start step-step, and not host your own images (i.e. not have a backend), and instead just start by using images already on the internet. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I will just stick with front end only for now. As a beginner it’s easy to over think it and confuse myself.